# IE - select2 always gets the focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use select2 plugin for my site. In IE, the problem encountered is that it always sets the focus on select2 frame.

```
<select class="form-control" name="categories[]" id="inputCate"  multiple="multiple">
```

//JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];
        $("#inputCate").select2({
          data: data,
          maximumSelectionLength: 2,

          placeholder: "Chuyên mục"

        });
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VwGGU/115/)

Comment: A few questions: Does this only happen in IE? If you remove the brackets from the `name` attribute (such that it is only `categories`), does the issue still happen? What do you mean by "always sets the focus on select2 frame"?

Comment: Hi Kevin ! This error only happens on IE, and if I remove the brackets in the name, I can not get the data that the user has selected. (I use PHP code). and here is the exact error when the page is loaded, the cursor always focus on select2 frame though I click the mouse pointer out other components of the site, the cursor remains in select2 taget the frame. Thank you for your interest in my question

Comment: I have the same question too

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in IE: input event occurs when placeholder text is applied. So you can:
     a) remove placeholder option
     b) Replace in select2.js

```
 this.$selection.on('input', '.select2-search--inline', function (evt) {
      // Unbind the duplicated `keyup` event
      self.$selection.off('keyup.search');
    });

    this.$selection.on('keyup.search input', '.select2-search--inline',
        function (evt) {
      self.handleSearch(evt);
    })
```

with

```
this.$selection.on('keyup.search', '.select2-search--inline',
    function (evt) {
  self.handleSearch(evt);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use last version [Select2 v4.0.1](https://select2.github.io/)

There were fixed many bugs

Comment: I had this exact same issue and upgrading to v4.0.2 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's IE placeholder bug. When js replace placeholder IE set focus.
My bad solution for jQuery and Select2 4.0.0

```js
    fixIePlaceholderSelect2 = function(select) {
        var placeholderFix = select.parent().find('.placeholder_ie_fix');
        if(select.val())
            placeholderFix.addClass('hide');
        placeholderFix.on("click", function () {
        select.select2("open");
            $(this).addClass('hide');
        });
        select.on("select2:open", function () {
            if(!select.val())
                placeholderFix.addClass('hide');
        });
        select.on("select2:close", function () {
            placeholderFix.removeClass('hide');
        });
    };


    fixIePlaceholderSelect2(
      $('select[name=services]')
    );
```

```css
 .placeholder_ie_fix {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -9px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .placeholder_ie_fix.hide {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="placeholder_ie_fix">My placeholder</div>
<select name="services" class="set_fix" multiple>
   <option>234</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder works fine if you avoid accents in it.

As @alexandr-nekrasov said, the problem is on the placeholder, but only if it contains accents. Try
`placeholder: "Chuyen mục"` and see if it works. Needs some tests but it worked for me.